# Include Prefix in Python Server Log

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I have a twisted Python application running and the logs are successfully generated for it. Here's the logs:

```
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 Log opened.
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 twistd 13.2.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.6) starting up.
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollR
eactor.
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 WebApplication starting on 7777
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 Starting factory <__builtin__.WebApplication instan
ce at 0x7ff71fd83f38>
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 Starting factory <olsr_client.JsonFactory instance 
at 0x7ff71fd83050>
```

All logs associated with the complete software are being saved in a single file. For the Twisted python, I would like to include a prefix in the logs so that concerned logs can be differentiated from other logs. example:

```
2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 [MABL] WebApplication starting on 7777
```

OR

```
[MABL]2019-02-13 15:57:44+0530 WebApplication starting on 7777
```

Is it possible to get it done in Twisted Python?

Comment: If this is using the normal `logging` module, play around with `basicConfig(format='%(module)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s')` or some such.

Comment: Hi @tripleee, thank you for the comment. This method works. However, I am not using logging module. I am using twisted.python.log.